# What serial protocol has 60hrz cycles?

Tags: reverse-engineering

I'm tapping the ribbon cable interface between a HVAC control board (relays, etc) and display board (membrane panel + led display) to reverse engineer how to change the set point programmatically. I came across these traces using a logic probe / oscilloscope. Small pulses are clearly occuring when keypresses occur, but I can't understand why they occur in reference to what appears to be a 60 hrz signal. My best guess is that somehow the AC line power is getting picked up by the logic probe but I can't see how since I see this pattern regardless if I ground to the chassis or a persistently zero volt pin on the wiring hardness.

Is there a serial communication protocol that looks like this? (Signal appears to be on channel 3 and 4).

Have already googled extensively for specs on a Ranco 7221081 PTAC control board and found nothing hence the need for reverse engineering.

[image: Scope Trace]

Comment: Looks like channel 3 and 4 are differential pair. And the 60 Hz signal is some kind of common-mode noise (or you have your reference wrong)

Comment: 'Hz' is the abbreviation for the SI unit 'hertz'. Note capitalisation in both cases. Capitals matter!

Comment: Interestingly 3 and 4 were not a differential pair. I had been expecting that too but it turns out they are plain 5V non-inverted TTL/5V serial signals, TX and RX separately, 8N1 4800 baud with an extra 9th signaling bit for address identification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It seems to be a faulty signal capture with an induced hum between all signals and the 0V reference pins.  Excessive lead length and coupling to finger which radiates E-Fields between the two.

Comment: Can you suggest an approach to definitively test which pin is the signal ground? Or do I just systematically try all of them?

Comment: How about an Ohmmeter to most likely ground to pins being tested

Comment: Through some process of elimination managed to figure out the ground and yes, the signal cleaned up. I had been triggering an immediate cold shutdown of the HVAC unit when I had previously attempted to place any leads on this pin, even just an ohmmeter, so I had mentally decided to avoid touching it again. But once I connected the logic analyzer up using that as GND (and ran the laptop only on battery power) I got clean, readable serial traffic. Tnx for the help.